# Session Timeout - Cookies / PHP

Tags: php, session-cookies

This is part of my code for login, I would like to logout users after 15 minutes, of inactivity ofcourse. Could you please advice me what to change, because im newbe to PHP...

```
        if ($rememberme)
        {
            setcookie ('USSUID', $_SESSION['uid'], time () + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
            setcookie ('USSPW', $_SESSION['upw'], time () + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setcookie ('USSUID', $_SESSION['uid'], time () + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
```

The relevant part to your solution is in the third parameter of setcookie. There you have to fill in the time when you want to let your cookie expire.

You have to change (1 year)

```
time () + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
```

to (15 minutes)

```
time () + 60 *15
```

That's it.

Comment: To add to this, you'll have to update the cookie on every page load, as otherwise the cookie will expire after 15 minutes and they'll be logged out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already making use of `$_SESSION`, add a timestamp each time a page is requested, but before test if the maximum amount of an active session is already over (compared to that timestamp). If it is, log the user out. Regenerate the session id as well.

This is independent to the session cookie itself.